# Why does sqlite3_bind seem to LOOP?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm using a few sqlite3_bind routines (in the iPhone SDK) as shown below to make a single update (INSERT or UPDATE) to a table:

```
        sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 1, aString, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(update_statement, 2, anInteger);
        sqlite3_bind_int(update_statement, 3, pk);
```

However, upon checking the updated table I discover unexpected results. I followed the progress using 'step over' in the Xcode Debugger and it looks like this group of three sqlite3_bind routines is being looped over so as to execute **MORE THAN ONCE** and I'm getting multiple inserts or updates when there should only be one. This routine is not inside of a while statement or anything so I'm puzzled.

Hope a person familiar with sqlite3 in the iPhone SDK can help.

Comment: It sounds like this has nothing to do with SQLite and you're just confused about your app's control flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops....It might help if the method containing the sqlite3_bind was not being called redundantly by another function elsewhere simultaneously LOL. I created a separate call to the function with the sqlite3_bind routines and completely neglected to delete the original call. Dumb mistake, solved: **sqlite3_bind does not LOOP.**